# Subdomain and main domain showing the same website

Tags: apache2, webserver

Recently I've tried to set up a subdomain where the main domain redirects to it by changing the URL by messing with `.htaccess`, `VirtualHost` and `apache2.conf`.

To do this I created two sites in `sites-available`, one is `default.conf` and one is `subdomain.conf`.

`default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoom /home/user/web/
</VirtualHost>
```

`subdomain.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/user/subdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

The weird thing with this is that when `subdomain.conf` is activated it becomes the default site for both the subdomain and the main domain when what I want is for the main domain site and directory to appear on `www.domain.com` and the subdomain to appear on `subdomain.domain.com`. When the subdomain is deactivated and default is activated it appears on both websites too.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Just put them both in default.conf you should also check over your default conf for spelling mistakes... `DocumentRoom`

Comment: Welp. Didn't realise you could do it in one config. It works now thanks! Want you make an answer so I can mark it? Spelling mistake was a copying mistake and wasn't in the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separate .conf for each site. You simply put them all in your default and you'll be good to go. Also check for spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter said:

> Just put them both in `default.conf` you should also check over your `default.conf`  for spelling mistakes...